# Using deeplink to open an Android app on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-deep-link

I'm implementing the deeplink function in Xamarin. The function didn't work as I expeceted.

If I click on a link in my Google Keep App it won't navigate to my app whent it on PAUSED mode (app is in the background). Instead, it open an Activity right in the Google Keep app. So, is there a away to resume my app after click on the deeplink on Keep Note app.

My current config on the `HomeActivity.cs`:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
              DataScheme = "https",
              DataHost = "example",
              DataPathPrefix = "",
              AutoVerify = true)

        ]
public class HomeActivity : BaseActivity
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: `If I click on a link on my Keep Note it won't navigate to my app that is on PAUSE mode. Instead, it open an Activity right in the Keep Note app.`  Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. What's the `on PAUSE mode` and `my Keep Note` ? How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: PAUSE means app is in the background and Keep Note is an app. Basically, I try to open a app with deeplinks from my note app. I have also edited the question.